# Manipulation events in UWP is not firing continuously while dynamically replacing any content

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, image-manipulation

I am having image placed in a grid and have subscribed the manipulation events for the grid to perform scaling for that image. When I dynamically replace the image source in the manipulation event, the pinch zooming(scaling) of the image is not performing continuously. I need to restart the zooming action for the new image. I have reproduced the issue in this [sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ImageEvents_(2)398752652)

Comment: If the answer has resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> When I dynamically replace the image source in the manipulation event, the pinch zooming(scaling) of the image is not performing continuously.

The problem is when you replacing image source, UI thread will terminate previous process. And `PointerExited` event handler will be invoked. I found you set  `touchCount` as 0. So zooming action will be terminated. For your requirement, you could remove `touchCount = 0` from `PointerExited` event handler then place it in `PointerReleased` event handler.

```
private void Grid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     touchCount = 0;     
 }
```